# Hide regions not available to AWS IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have bounded an IAM user to a region. Whenever the user goes to another region it shows "API Error".
Is it possible to hide the regions the IAM user does not have access to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, there is no way in AWS Console you can hide the region that is being guarded by IAM Permissions.
The user will can still see it on the AWS Console UI , however they will get "API Error" as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

AWS does not have any option for that yet. However you can [enable/disable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws-enable-disable-regions.html) a region which are not enabled for your account by default.